# Incompatible pointer type - Trying to modify array from another function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have an array:

```
char gameBoard[6][6];
// Initilize the array
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    for(int o = 0;o < 6;o++) {
        gameBoard[i][o] = ' ';
    }
}
```

Later in my code I have a function I am trying to use that will modify this array:

```
void placePiece(char piece, char *gameBoard) {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    gameBoard[posXInArray][posYInArray] = piece;
}
```

I am calling the function from the same scope as where the `gameBoard` array is created and initialized.

```
placePiece('X', gameBoard);
```

The warning I get doing this:

```
warning: passing argument 2 of ‘placePiece’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
    placePiece('X', gameBoard);
    ^
note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[6]’
 void placePiece(char piece, char *gameBoard);
```

I am confused as to what I am doing wrong? I assumed to modify the array from another function I would pass the pointer so that I could directly modify the array. Is this incorrect? I have also tried `&gameBoard` in the call with the same warning message. I'm guessing I am doing something silly that is incorrect?

Comment: shouldn't it be `void placePiece(char piece, char ** gameBoard);` since it's a 2D array?

Comment: @VHarisop I added what another one of the `notes` is to my post if that helps. Using `**` did not fix it.

Comment: @VHarisop that wouldn't work `char ** != (char [6][6] == char (*)[6])`.

Comment: @iharob ah, you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass the 2-dimensional array to this function

```
void placePiece(char piece, char *gameBoard)
```

I think this would work fine for you

```
void placePiece(char piece, unsigned int size, char gameBoard[size][size])
```

you can use it this way

```
placePiesce('X', 6, gameBoard);
```

or better

```
placePiesce('X', sizeof(gameBoard) / sizeof(gameBoard[0]), gameBoard);
```

and since the type of `gameBoard[0]` is `char` this will also work

```
placePiesce('X', sizeof(gameBoard), gameBoard);
```

because `sizeof(gameBoard[0]) == 1` in that case.

Comment: I want to modify the array, not just use it.

Comment: @Fogest It will be modified, don't worry. Try it and see.

Comment: @Fogest you can neither modify nor use the array if you pass the wrong type. `char *` is used for one-dimensional arrays.

Comment: This will only allow me to modify the gameBoard within this scope, not the calling functions scope. @VHarisop

Comment: @Fogest No, it will modify it everywhere, trust me. Just try it.

Comment: It works! Can you explain how this works? Because I thought this would only be affecting the things within its scope?

Comment: @Fogest When the argument is passed it's passed as `int(*)[6]` to the function, so it's passed as a pointer to an array of 6 elemnts.